# Can't tell which questions have been marked answered in the sorted question view

Tags: bug, design

When I go to [the main page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) I can easily see which questions have been marked answered with a green circle, like this:

[image]

If I click on the [Questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) button, I can't discern which have been answered and which haven't

[image]

Is it just me or are other folks seeing this too?

Comment: Yeah, the CSS is definitely messed up, overriding the proper styles with ones that are identical to answered. There was a change to SO's accepted/answered styles recently, so I suspect something got changed across most of the sites.

Comment: Looks like the same problem I brought up here: [Indicator of “accepted answer” is not displayed in /questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/indicator-of-accepted-answer-is-not-displayed-in-questions). Must not be an easy fix...

Comment: @user3169 I could have sworn I had seen another post about it, but I couldn't find it. I voted to close this as a duplicate of yours.